# OSMnx Add Title to Graph Plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, title, networkx, osmnx

I'm using the wonderful [OSMnx library](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) created by Geoff Boeing. I am plotting a street network based on one of his [tutorials](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/06-example-osmnx-networkx.ipynb). Everything works perfectly. However, I would like to plot more than 40 graphs, using different centralities. Therefore, I would like to add a title with each district and centrality name to each plot. Currently, it looks like this.

[Plotted OSMnx Street Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkLym.png)

This is what my code looks like.

```
def display_most_important_node(G_centralities_sorted_dict, G_dictionary, district, centrality_measure='betweenness_centrality'):
    node_color = ['red' if node == G_centralities_sorted_dict[district][centrality_measure][0][0] else '#336699' for node in ox.project_graph(G_dictionary[district]).nodes()]
    node_size = [40 if node == G_centralities_sorted_dict[district][centrality_measure][0][0] else 20 for node in ox.project_graph(G_dictionary[district]).nodes()]

    fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G_dictionary[district]), annotate=False, edge_linewidth=1.5, node_size=node_size, fig_height=10, node_color=node_color, node_zorder=2)
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately it is quite hard to help you with the code you show. Please post your problem as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain clearly what doesn't work. This way you will receive help much quicker.

Comment: Hey @ThomasKühn. Thanks a bunch for your input. I've updated my initial post and hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I don't know that library, but it looks like what `ox.plot_graph` returns is a `pyplot.Figure` and a `pyplot.Axes`. If that is true, you should be able to use the normal matplotlib functions on these methods. Try if `ax.set_title('the title')` or `fig.suptitle('the other title')` does what you want.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasKühn. That was my initial thought. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I also tried `fig.text(.73, .834, 'title', fontsize=16)` but again no success.

Comment: I had a look at the source code and the `fig, ax` tuple is indeed generated with `plt.subplots()`, but the function calls `plt.show()` itself by default. Try adding the keywords `show=False` and `close = False` to your `ox.plot_graph` call. Then, do `ax.set_title('test')` and then do `plt.show()`.

Comment: It worked! You are amazing @ThomasKühn. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I formulated it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the functions of the OSMnx package call `plt.show()` already before they return the `fig` and `ax` handles, which means you can no longer manipulate the `Figure` and `Axes` instances (my guess is that this is done to prevent distortion of the Figure after creation). This is done using a special function called `save_and_show()`, which is called internally. You can prevent the showing of the figure by passing the keywords `show=False` and `close=False` to the according plotting function (`close=False` is needed because figures that are not automatically shown are by default closed within `save_and_show()`). With these keywords used, `fig` and `ax` can be manipulated after the function call, but now `plt.show()` has to be called explicitly. Here still a complete example following the OP:

```
def display_most_important_node(G_centralities_sorted_dict, G_dictionary, district, centrality_measure='betweenness_centrality'):
    node_color = ['red' if node == G_centralities_sorted_dict[district][centrality_measure][0][0] else '#336699' for node in ox.project_graph(G_dictionary[district]).nodes()]
    node_size = [40 if node == G_centralities_sorted_dict[district][centrality_measure][0][0] else 20 for node in ox.project_graph(G_dictionary[district]).nodes()]

    fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G_dictionary[district]), annotate=False, edge_linewidth=1.5, node_size=node_size, fig_height=10, node_color=node_color, node_zorder=2, show=False, close=False)

    ax.set_title('subplot title')
    fig.suptitle('figure title')
    plt.show()
```

Note that not all OSMnx functions accept the `show` and `close` keywords. For instance, `plot_shape` does not. Hope this helps.